# Why is curses on linux giving me following error?

Tags: c, linker, curses, undefined-reference

Trying to get getch() working to capture key press.

```
    #include <curses.h>
    ...
    ...
    WINDOW *w;
    char f;

   w = initscr();
   timeout(3000);
   f = getch();
   endwin();
```

is giving me following error:-

```
undefined reference to `wgetch'
undefined reference to `stdscr'
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

That's a linking error.  Are you linking to the curses library correctly?

There are two steps involved in using a library in C.

1. You `#include` the relevant header files from your source files.  This is so your code knows what signatures of the library functions are.  So you're doing this correctly.
2. When compiling your code, you need to tell the linker to link to the relevant libraries, so it can find the definition of those functions.  **This is what you're not doing**.  Assuming you're using gcc then adding `-lncurses` to the compile line should do it.  Here's an [explanation of linking](http://www.network-theory.co.uk/docs/gccintro/gccintro_17.html).

Comment: link to curses using -lncurses option

Comment: FWIW, in November 2017 it is better to use `pkg-config`, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47060434/841108) answer to a very similar question.

Answer (score 0):

The above answers are correct but the format is:

`gcc -Wall program.c -o name_of_binary -lncurses`

When I did:

`gcc -Wall -lncurses program.c...`

It did not work so apparently it should be tacked on the end.

Comment: `-Wall` I use for debugging.