# getting a char from keyboard using curses.h

Tags: c, gcc, linker, curses

I'm trying to get a character from the keyboard using curses.h.
This is my source (get_char_example.c):

```
#include <curses.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char ch;

    printf("Enter a character: ");
    ch = getch();
    printf("\nIts ASCII code is %d\n", ch);

    return 0;
}
```

I use the following command to compile:

```
gcc get_char_example.c -o get_char_example
```

And I get the following error:

/tmp/ccjaXwRU.o: In function `main':

```
get_char_example.c:(.text+0x1c): undefined reference to `stdscr'
get_char_example.c:(.text+0x24): undefined reference to `wgetch'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

using: gcc (GCC) 7.2.0
Arch Linux 4.13.9-1-ARCH

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is curses on linux giving me following error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1513417/why-is-curses-on-linux-giving-me-following-error)

Comment: I believe it is not a duplicate. However the question lacks indeed of research efforts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a linker error (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1513417/why-is-curses-on-linux-giving-me-following-error), nearly a duplicate). `ncurses` is generally known to [pkg-config](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/pkg-config/) (which gives more dependencies, when required), so try to compile with:

```
 gcc -Wall -Wextra -g \
    $(pkg-config --cflags ncurses) \
    get_char_example.c \
    $(pkg-config --libs ncurses)
```

<sup>You want to [Invoke GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Invoking-GCC.html) with all warnings and debug info; you would [use GDB](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/), perhaps under `emacs` or with `ddd`, for debugging.</sup>

Even better, use some [build automation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Build_automation) tool (like [`make`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make) or `ninja`). With [GNU `make`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/index.html) take inspiration from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20146082/841108) to write your  [`Makefile`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Makefile) (where <kbd>tab</kbd>-s are significant).

On my Debian Sid, `pkg-config --cflags ncurses` gives `-D_GNU_SOURCE -D_DEFAULT_SOURCE` and `pkg-config --libs ncurses` gives `-lncurses -ltinfo`, so simply linking with `-lncurses` is *not* enough (and that is why [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1513417/why-is-curses-on-linux-giving-me-following-error) is not exactly a duplicate today in November 2017; a few years ago linking with simply `-lncurses` was enough, today it is not).

Use `pkg-config --list-all` to find all the packages and libraries known to [pkg-config](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/pkg-config/); when developing *your* libraries consider also providing some `.pc` file for it.

BTW, your program should start by initializing with `initscr` and use `printw`; Read [Ncurses-programming-HowTo](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/NCURSES-Programming-HOWTO/) even if it is a bit old.

Notice also that using ASCII in the 21<sup>st</sup> century is obsolete. **Programs** and computers **use [UTF-8 everywhere](http://utf8everywhere.org/)**, and this has profound consequences you should be aware of (since an [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) character can span *several* bytes). My French keyboard has keys for `²`, `§`, `€` and `é` (even with American keyboards your could paste them) and none of these are in ASCII. Consider also using some UTF-8 library like [libunistring](https://www.gnu.org/software/libunistring/manual/libunistring.html).

Comment: Why is that not a duplicate? They are clearly not linking with the library as covered by the answer in that duplicate

Comment: Because the other answer don't mention `pkg-config` and on some distributions, notably my Debian Sid, `ncurses` depend on other libraries.

Comment: Find a better duplicate then, rather than trying to score some quick and easy points from a common question

Comment: I leave you to find one. I tried quickly to find a duplicate, and failed.

Comment: But the one you found is not correct today in 2017 on Debian/Sid. It was correct a few years ago. `ncurses` depend now on `tinfo` and that was not the case in distributions a few years ago. Teaching newbies to use `pkg-config` when relevant is worthwhile, the other answer don't even mention it.

Comment: @Basile Starynkevitch: So it compiles using your advice. But when I run it I get: `Enter a character: 
Its ASCII code is -1` But I do not touch the keyboard. It runs automatically. Obviously the further debugging is a problem ob my source. But the command works!